# Is time spent in data collection considered "contribution" in Academia?

Tags: publications, research-process, data

I've been educated that the correct scientific theory and analysis are far more important than the data collection.

Let's compare the two papers. The first group of authors collected their data for two years, but they have done very poor analysis, and lead to laughable results.

The second paper simply uses the data from the first group; however, their method is far more rigorous and they got a rigorous result.

Which one is more valuable to academia?

Comment: You asked two questions which are quite different from each other.  The second question is opinion based, which is not allowed here.  I think you should reconsider these questions because they just asks for a vague judgement of the importance of essential things.

Comment: The ICJME views conception and design of a study, and the acquisition, analysis, or interpretation of data as equally valuable - and says you have to have contributed to at least one to qualify for authorship. That may be different outside medicine, but I don’t see why it should. http://www.icmje.org/recommendations/browse/roles-and-responsibilities/defining-the-role-of-authors-and-contributors.html

Comment: Nothing is "more important". Both are necessary for the advance of science.

Comment: "but they have done very poor analysis, and lead to laughable results." This way of saying it and the question in general suggest a lack of understanding of the different talents needed in academia, especially in interdisciplinary research. Aquiring data e.g. by experiments needs other talents than data analysis, and the best result can be expected when disciplines work together. The different talents are equally important.

Comment: I don't consider the question opinion-based and I have edited to drop _in your opinion_ from the question. My answer proposes that "neither is more important," which has been echoed in comments above and is supported by ICJME. I have nominated the question for reopening.

Comment: High GPA, can you edit your title? To avoid the issue raised by @AnonymousPhysicist

Comment: @user2768 the issue raised by AnonymousPhysicist (which I agree with) is about the question at the end "Which one is more valuable?", not about the title. I think the title is perfectly fine as a question. But asking  "which one is more valuable?" is akin to the well-known "what is more important: theoretical physics or applied physics?", which naturally will be answered differently by theoretical and applied physicists. In my view, focusing on the title and asking whether pure data collection is well-received by the community would make it less opinion-based.

Comment: @wimi AnonymousPhysicist opens with *You asked two questions*, which is why I suggested editing the title, to ensure there's just one.  (Two questions is a problem.) I think the question in the main body is the one the OP wants to ask, because that's what the body is about. That said, the question in the title is also an interesting one.

Answer (score 2):

> I've been educated that the correct scientific theory and analysis are far more important than the data collection.

**I disagree: Neither is more important.**

In your example, the second paper may not have been possible without the first. Similarly, perhaps third, fourth, and fifth papers could be written given the first, maybe independently of each other and the second. In this scenario, paper one is more important, it provided the basis for future works. But, maybe the second group could have collected their own data, then paper one has less value.

**It really depends on the circumstances, I don't think there's a general answer.**